# Reducing and enlarging text from a single point

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm trying to make an animation. The essence of the animation is that when scrolling down, the text decreases, and if up, it increases. And when scrolling down it should remain fixed. But I have a problem: when you zoom in and out, the text is not linked to any point, so it is more clear to attach a gif

An example of how it should be: [Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BakD8.jpg)
An example of what actually happens: [Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MW63M.jpg)

HTML

```
<div class="main__logo">
     <h1 id="logo">
          Fashion
     </h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main__logo {
  font-size: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.main__logo .logo__sticky {
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-top: -80px;
}
#logo {
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  -o-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 80) {
    $("#logo").addClass("logo__sticky");
  } else {
    $("#logo").removeClass("logo__sticky");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [animate](https://animate.style/) it will make it easier for you to animate every frame just like the video.